# How to trigger nginx-rtmp pull from the ingest server on client requests a .m3u8 video through load balancer

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I have a ingest nginx-rtmp server which act as a single source of rtmp streams for worker nodes.
Ingest instance gets the rtmp through OBS. Now when client request a video through load balancer like https://load-balancer.com/hls/test.m3u8
Load balancer sends this request to one of the worker nodes.

The worker nodes has following nginx config file.

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

# Define the Application
        application show {
            live on;
            pull rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/ live=1;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }

    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    aio on;
    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }

            root /mnt/;
        }
    }
}
```

The nginx-rtmp pull of this worker node will not work until anyone request for it. Hence it will not generate the hls file for the http request.

Note: I can not push the stream to the worker nodes as the worker noders are being auto scalled and does not have a fix number.

I wasn to know a solution by which, Whenever a client request a video which and the worker node gets the https request, Some how the rtmp server application show gets a hit and pull the video from the ingest server and generates the hls block and the http request can be fulfilled.